# Filter an array based on attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I will love to filter an object array based on value passed and return a modified array.

for example:

```
let jsonData = [
          {
            "id": "300",
            "name": "item1",
            "showtimes": ["December 28, 2021", "December 30, 2021"]
          },
          {
            "id": "223",
            "name": "item2",
            "showtimes": ["January, 4 2022"]
          },
          {
            "id": "888",
            "name": "item3",
            "showtimes": ["December 28, 2021", "December 25, 2021", "December 29, 2021"]
          },
        ]
```

I will love to get this modified array when "December 28, 2021" is passed :

```
     [
          {
            "id": "300",
            "name": "item1",
            "showtimes": ["December 28, 2021", "December 30, 2021"]
          },               {
            "id": "888",
            "name": "item3",
            "showtimes": ["December 28, 2021", "December 25, 2021", "December 29, 2021"]
          },
        ]
```

This is what I have currently but not giving the desired array:

```
const result = jsonData.map((x) => {
    return x.showtimes.filter(y => y === 'December 28, 2021');
    })
```

Comment: Use `Array.filter` See on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @tromgy I tried that but it only returns the date and not the modified array. Can you check the edited question to see if I am doing it right

Comment: ```jsonData.filter((x) => {
    return x.showtimes.includes( 'December 28, 2021');
    })```

Answer (score 0):

Use `includes` and return the whole element

```
const result = jsonData.map((x) => {
if (x.showtimes.includes('December 28, 2021')) {
  return x;
}})    

[{
  id: "300",
  name: "item1",
  showtimes: ["December 28, 2021", "December 30, 2021"]
}, undefined, {
  id: "888",
  name: "item3",
  showtimes: ["December 28, 2021", "December 25, 2021", "December 29, 2021"]
}]
```